# Jellyfish gulf of Thailand

Tags: species-identification

I found may such jellyfishes on the Hua Hin beach in 27.11.2018. They measure around 25 cm.

Since I'm more botanist, I have big problem to identify it. Google doesn't help me a lot (spent 3 hours googling and nothing).

Anyone know latin name?[image]

Comment: So in a 3 minute search for blue-rimmed Thai jellyfish...Doesn't look like [*Rhizostoma pulmo*](https://www.123rf.com/photo_2102684_jellyfish-rhizostoma-pulmo.html), *Aequorea*, or [*Cyanea lamarckii*](https://pixabay.com/photos/jellyfish-blue-cyanea-lamarckii-3177789/),

Comment: However,  others have seen similar specimens to yours: see [here](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/purple-blue-dead-jellyfish-sanae-beach-788695156), [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/eddingrid/31671279878/in/photostream/), and [here](https://farm2.static.flickr.com/1933/31718041168_ebac37a77c_b.jpg). I'll sleuth a bit more for you in a little bit....